# Некорректное отображение вывода из файла

Tags: java

Необходимо вывести данные из файла Фамилия-Цифра. Если фамилия повторилась, то цифры сложить.

Пользуюсь встроенным в Windows блокнотом.

Ввод:
Петров 0.501
Иванов 1.35
Петренко 1
Петров 0.85
Петренко 0.25

Все числа складываются, имена сортируются. Но что бы я не добавлял, вывод всегда корректный кроме одной строки. Петров 0.501 всегда выбрасывается последний и не складывается с предыдущим.

ВЫВОД:
Иванов 1.35
Петренко 1.25
Петров 0.85
Петров 0.501

```html
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        String line;
        Map<String, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (map.containsKey(line.split(" ")[0])) {
                map.replace(line.split(" ")[0], map.get(line.split(" ")[0]) + Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[1]));
            } else {
                map.put(line.split(" ")[0], Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[1]));
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> pair: map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
        }
```

[image: Код]

[image: Файл]

[image: Вывод]

[image: Цифры]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так я чуток подправил код,

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      URI uri = App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt").toURI();
      try (FileReader file = new FileReader(new File(uri))) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line;
        Map<String, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          String key = line.split(" ")[0].trim();
          String value = line.split(" ")[1].trim();
          System.out.println("Read " + key + ": " + value);
          if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.replace(key, map.get(key) + Double.parseDouble(value));
            System.out.println("Updated Map " + key + ": " + map.get(key));
          } else {
            map.put(key, Double.parseDouble(value));
            System.out.println("Added Map " + key + ": " + map.get(key));
          }
        }
        System.out.println("Output:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> pair : map.entrySet()) {
          System.out.println(pair.getKey() + ": " + pair.getValue());
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

ресурсный текст файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, лучше результат `line.split` сохранять в переменную, чтобы несколько раз не дёргать метод.

Comment: Ну это то ясно. Это как пример потенциальной ошибки

Comment: Добавил тримы, добавил переменные, менял имена в файле. Ничего не помогло. Более того, если добавляешь 3 одинаковых, то первый в файле будет отдельно стоять в конце мапы, а второй и третий складываются. Даже если ставишь первую строку перед циклом одноразово через map.put, все равно то же самое

Comment: Да интересно, завтра попробую сам срепродюсить

Comment: Тупо запустил проект и у меня вот такие результаты. Остаётся только то что у вас либо изменённых копий файла куча и вы путаете пути либо ещё что-то (версия сборки ...)

Comment: Да, я вставил ваш код, ничего не изменилось. Думаю проблема в "еще что-то")) Будем искать дальше, спасибо))

Comment: @yeahbaby поставьте точку останова на if и дебагайте

Comment: Измените файл, и покажите вводные и результаты на скрине как я показал. Все говорят что сделали но не договаривают всегда чего нибудь

Comment: Aziz, добавил скрины в шапку) Написал так, потому что сомневался, что Вам интересно продолжать исследование данной проблемы) И Дмитрию, точка ставилась в первую очередь, только толку от нее, я получаю false и иду в else

Comment: Это конечно бред, сделайте скрины только с цифрами. 1 1,  2 1, ...

Comment: У меня всё же сомнения по символам в тексте

Comment: Повторение не происходит к примеру по Б которой нет в латинице

Comment: @AzizUmarov Добавил в шапку с цифрами.. я могу даже дать доступ через teamviewer

Comment: Бред полный. Слов больше нет. У вас что-то там не так как у всех. Извините потратил столько времени только чтоб доказать что у вас не все в порядке с машиной. Но ещё к примеру у меня только java 14 но у вас я вижу 8 и ещё что-то там.

Comment: Давайте в zoom чтоб поглядеть и поменять если что

Comment: Дайте Адмит пожалуйста

Comment: Проблема решена. Связана была с кривой кодировкой самого файла. Большое спасибо Aziz Umarov за помощь!